# Determining Orthogonal Plane from 2 other points

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

I am preparing for an upcoming test and this is a question I have some confusion about.

Determine orthogonal plane,
x - 2y - 3z = 5;
-5x + 2y - 3z = 7;

Is the orthogonal plane simply just 6a - 4b = 0? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: are you aware about normal vector to a plane and about cross poduct?

Comment: Hello, i have not learnt cross product yet therefore I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- consider the normal vectors of the two given planes $n_1=(1,-2,-3)$ and $n_2=(-5,2,-3)$
- use cross product to find $n_3=n_1\times n_2$

Comment: By doing the cross product, i have n3 = (12, 18, -8).
So the orthogonal plane equation is simply 12x + 18y - 8z = 0?

Thanks!

Comment: @ChongYewHeng Yes it is an orthogonal plane you can simplify to 6x+9y-4z=0 and check directly that it works. Note that the orthogonal plane are inifinitely many with equation 6x+9y-4z=d. For d=0 we obtain the orthogonal plane through the origin.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this question without using cross product?

Comment: yes of course you can take ax+by+cz=0 and set the conditions for orthogonality

Comment: Does this just means the dot product of n1 and n2 = 0 (Conditions of Orthogonality) = ax + by + cz

Comment: Yes exactly , $n_1\cdot n_3=0$ and $n_2\cdot n_3=0$